# How to add extra data to collection from maatwebsite/Excel

Tags: excel, laravel, file-upload

I'm using the package `maatwebsite/excel v2.1` to import users to the page.

I have uploaded the file but I want to show the user before hand what he is importing and what rows can't be imported (because missing data or user already exist), but for this I would like to add at least 2 extra fields, 1 will tell me if the row can be uploaded (aesthetic purpose) and the order with a text telling him why it can not be imported that row.

I get the file rows like this

```
$users = Excel::load($ruta.'/'.$filename, function ($reader) {
})->get();
```

This return this collection, which for the first value, an user has the email `test@subject.com` assigned, and the second the `rif` field is bad formatted

```
[
    {
        "email": "test@subject.com",
        "empresa": "business1",
        "encargado": "person1",
        "rif": "J-12345-1",
    },
    {
        "email": "test@subject2.com",
        "empresa": "business2",
        "encargado": "Person 2",
        "rif": "123456-2",

    }
]
```

what I want is to add extra fields like this

```
[
    {
        "email": "test@subject.com",
        "empresa": "business1",
        "encargado": "person1",
        "rif": "J-12345-1",
        "validity": 0,
        "reason": "Email is already used"
    },
    {
        "email": "test@subject2.com",
        "empresa": "business2",
        "encargado": "Person 2",
        "rif": "123456-2",
        "validity": 0,
        "reason": "the rif field is badly formatted" 
    }
]
```

As I said, these fields are not meant to be saved in the document, but for showing the user a legend of what will be imported, what not and why not.

I know that I can check inside the callback function what I need, but how could I insert those values to the collection?

Comment: ...into which collection?  Could you give an example of what data you want to add, and where?

Comment: edited as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use `map()` method for the manipulate all collection item.

```
$users = Excel::load($ruta.'/'.$filename, function ($reader) {
})->get();

$newUsers = $users->map(function($user){
return [
        "email" => $user->email,
        "empresa" => $user->empresa,
        "encargado" => $user->encargado,
        "rif" => $user->rif,
        // make your controls and add new items here
        "validity" => $validate,
        "reason" => $reason

    ]
})
```

But note that, we are sending array back. When you try to to access data in iteration (probably in your view), you cant say $user->email, it will throws `Trying to get property of non-object` So you should say `$user["email"]` ..